# У меня есть класс который находится в namespace стандартных ассетов(car controller) в нём мне нужно использовать класс без namespace

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Вопрос по unity У меня есть класс который находится в namespace стандартных ассетов(car controller) в нём мне нужно использовать класс без namespace(whels_for_bild), что делать?
Если добавить namespace whels_for_bild и подключить этот namespace в car controller через using, то он(namespace) не виден в car controller

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                // m_WheelColliders[0].steerAngle = m_SteerAngle;
                // m_WheelColliders[1].steerAngle = m_SteerAngle;
                if (m_WheelColliders[i] != null)
                {
                  m_WheelColliders[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Whels_for_bild>();//тут не работает
                    if (m_WheelColliders[i].transform.position.x > 0)
                    {
                        m_WheelColliders[i].steerAngle = m_SteerAngle;
                       // print(m_WheelColliders[i].transform.position.x);
                    }
                    if (m_WheelColliders[i].gameObject.transform.position.x < 0)
                    {
                        m_WheelColliders[i].steerAngle = -m_SteerAngle;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `Whels_for_bild` != `whels_for_bild`. И так, чисто ради интереса, посмотрите в интернете, как пишется то, что вы написали в названии класса. Покажите сам класс в неймспейсе, покажите `using`, которым вы подключили неймспейс.

Comment: Для использования класса без неймспейса `using` не нужен. Не работать в конкретном случае может по разным причинам, например ваш `whels_for_bild`(посмотри как пишется что бы не чурковать и не позориться) не наследуется от `MonoBehaviour`, а следовательно не является компонентом.